# dtoverlay=gpio-poweroff not working on raspberry pi 3 B

Tags: power, power-supply, kernel, power-management, device-tree

### Problem:

I have a Raspi 3B rev: a02082   (Q1 2016 3 Model B  1.2     1 GB    (Mfg by Sony)) running raspbian jessie kernel 4.9.35-v7

I want to signal to a power management circuit that filesystems have been un-mounted and now we can remove the power from the raspberry pi.

The

`dtoverlay=gpio-poweroff,active_low=y`

option when set in /boot/cmdline.txt is supposed to drive GPIO26 low after shutdown.

However, watching the pin on a scope, it stays at 0 volt irrespective of the state of the Pi (booted/shutdown)

I have tried changing the pin numbers in the `dtoverlay=gpio-poweroff` parameters, also I have tried with and without the active_low option.

The GPIO pin is functional - because if I test with:

`echo "26" > /sys/class/gpio/export
echo "out" > /sys/class/gpio/gpio26/direction
echo "1" > /sys/class/gpio/gpio26/value`

I can see the pin go high on the oscilloscope.

### Questions

- 1: Why might it not be working?
- 2: How can we debug the overlay?
- 3: Should we expect a spike/edge on the pin by
  the overlay on shutdown - or a continuous low/high?

Answer (score 1):

It MIGHT have something to do with:-

```
    active_low              Set if the power control device requires a
                            high->low transition to trigger a power-down.
                            Note that this will require the support of a
                            custom dt-blob.bin to prevent a power-down
                            during the boot process, and that a reboot
                            will also cause the pin to go low.
```

Frankly I have never been able to make head nor tail of this cryptic "documentation", but it works perfectly on my Pi without using this parameter.

Comment: Thanks for a response! 
I tried it with and without - not working either ways - :(

Is your's a Raspberry Pi 3 B?

Answer (score 0):

I have had both of these work to force pin 17 low after shutdown. Not sure if this will work for your situation or with any other pins.

option 1.
edit /boot/config.txt
add this

```
dtoverlay=gpio-poweroff,gpiopin=17,active_low=1
```

option 2
run this from command line

```
sudo dtoverlay -v gpio-poweroff gpiopin=17 active_low=1
```